# Powershell: Exclude Temporary Files from FileSystemWatcher

Tags: powershell, temporary-files

I am using a `$watcher` (`FileSystemWatcher`) to trigger an `$action`, when a docx-File is being created or changed in a directory:

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\ExportedDocuments"
$watcher.Filter = "*.docx*"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  
$action = [scriptblock]::Create('
### here is my complete script
')
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
while ($true) {}
```

Unfortunately, in the directory where the `$watcher` (`FileSystemWatcher`) is looking through, sometimes temporary files are created:

> 01/23/2019 07:53:52, Created, C:\ExportedDocuments\~$FFFFFFFF.docx

Which means that temporary files are also detected by the `$watcher` (`FileSystemWatcher`) and force the `$action` to run.

Is there a way, to exclude these temporary files from the `$watcher`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter?view=netframework-4.7.2) you can't have multiple filters :

> Use of multiple filters such as "*.txt|*.doc" is not supported.

However you can put the filter in your $action.  For example :

```
$action = { $fileName = Split-Path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath -leaf

            if ($fileName -like '~$*') { $logline = "$(Get-Date), $fileName, 'TEMP'"}
            else { $logline = "$(Get-Date), $fileName, 'NOT TEMP'" }

            Add-content "D:\test\log.txt" -value $logline
          }
```

Produces output like this :

```
01/23/2019 11:37:37, ~$f.docx, 'TEMP'
01/23/2019 11:37:37, ~$f.docx, 'TEMP'
01/23/2019 11:38:29, New Microsoft Word Document.docx, 'NOT TEMP'
```

So to simply exclude temporary files based on your '~$' pattern you could make $action like :

```
$action = { $fileName = Split-Path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath -leaf
            if (-not ($fileName -like '~$*')) {
              # Do whatever
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Your handler will have to determine which file is a temp file and ignore it. In case of MSWord temp files: name starting with a tilde (~) and/or hidden attribute

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a code sample for me?

Comment: Not now, but I saw @lx07 has provided a code sample in another answer