# Pick up 2 file extensions in a directory using FileSystemWatcher

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I am looking to pick up only pdf and rtf files but I get a result of "true" when echoing the variable

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher 
Write-Host "First line of the script, getting the watcher folder " $watcher -ForegroundColor white
$watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Demo Site"
Write-Host "This is the current path " $watcher.Path -ForegroundColor white
$watcher.Filter = "*.rtf" -or "*.pdf" 
Write-Host "Filtering by: " $watcher.Filter -ForegroundColor white
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
Write-Host "Including Subdirectories" -ForegroundColor white
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$action = {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $path2 = $path.replace("C:\Users\", "")
    $path2 = $path2.replace("\","/")
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $logline = "$(Get-Date -Format F) , File was $changeType in:  $path"
    $logFile = "D:\MoveLog.txt"

    Add-content -Path $logFile -value $logline  
    # moves the file captured by the watcher
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl "/sites/1/$path2" 
        -TargetUrl "/sites/2" -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists 
        -Force -Confirm:$True 
        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError
    # added to make sure that the larger files finish uploading
    If ($ProcessError)
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "File not copied!"
        Write-Warning -Message "Waiting 5 seconds and trying again"
        Start-Sleep -s 5
        $logFile = "D:\MoveLog.txt"
        Add-content -Path $logFile -value " $(Get-Date -Format F),  Error while Copying file - Let's try this again!"
        Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl "/sites/1/$path2" 
            -TargetUrl "/sites/1/$path2" -Force -Confirm:$False 
            -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError
        If ($ProcessError)
        {
            Write-Warning -Message "File not copied!"
            Write-Warning -Message $error[0].Exception.Message
            $errorLog = " $(Get-Date -Format F),  $error[0].Exception.Message"
            Write-Host  "12. Writing to Log" -ForegroundColor red
            $logFile = "D:\MoveLog.txt"
            Add-content -Path $logFile -value $errorLog
                $to_mail = ""
                $fr_mail = ""
                $subject = "An error has occured when moving in SharePoint"
                $serverDetails = ""
                $port = 
            Send-MailMessage -To $to_mail -From $fr_mail -Subject $subject -Body $errorLog 
                -Priority High -SmtpServer $serverDetails -Port $port
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host  "n 8. After 1 error, Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library" -ForegroundColor green
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host  "n 8. Successfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library with no errors" -ForegroundColor green
    }
}
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
# Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
while($true){
    sleep 5
}
```

How can I change `$watcher.Filter = "*.rtf" -or "*.pdf"` to just pick up the 2 files?

When I pick up all file extensions .tmp gets picked up as well but by the time I get to do something with it, it gets deleted so produces a FAIL message.

Also I have tried `dir .\* -include ('*.xsl', '*.xslt') -recurse`

I don't get an error but when I echo the `$watcher.Filter` with 2 extensions I get `true`

Comment: Wasn't aware of the FileSystemWatcher until now, but reading documentation, Filter should be a string. Your expression, `$watcher.Filter = "*.rtf" -or "*.pdf"` sets the filter to the boolean result **True**

Comment: Several options found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965184/how-to-set-filter-for-filesystemwatcher-for-multiple-file-types)

Comment: thanks, the link only works for C#, i cant get it to work in powershell

Comment: Edit your question to show updated code & explain what "can't get it to work" means: error messages? no output?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795933/powershell-and-system-io-filesystemwatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31795933/3439404). Set `$watcher.Filter = '*.*'` and filter extensions in the _action_ block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell: Exclude Temporary Files from FileSystemWatcher](https://superuser.com/questions/1397308/powershell-exclude-temporary-files-from-filesystemwatcher)

Comment: @JosefZ it's not a duplicate as the other refers to msWord and that has a solution of adding in ~ as a filter.
For me that wont work since I want to use pdf's or rtf's

Comment: I added in the entire code so hopefully it will be more clear on what I'm trying to do

Comment: Why would it not work? It does the same. It's the same problem. You will have to adapt your solution but the same approach should work? It would just be an extension to your action block (which would run more often as you'd go for *.* or something)? Why not just register multiple watchers if you need to watch for both?

Comment: @Seth ok, it took me a bit of tweaking, editing. Now i have a duplicate code but at least it works

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer. The action code should either be the same or just contain switch.

Comment: @Seth solution posted below, keep in mind that it contains a bug where sometimes files don't copy

Answer (score 0):

After few errors I managed to get this working,

I created this script to move files between to SharePoint libraries so that documents don't take up space on the server.

Basically:

1. Files are written to a synced OneDrive folder on server using through an ERP
2. Get picked up by FileSystemWatcher
3. Get moved to Archive library where users can access it.

You will need `SharePointPnP`

```
Connect-PnpOnline -Url https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/ -UseWebLogin
#disconects from Sharepoint
#disconnect-PnpOnline 

$logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
#for debugging 
start-transcript

### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
Write-Host "First line of the script, getting the watcher folder " $watcher -ForegroundColor white
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Demo Site - Staging"
Write-Host "This is the current path " $watcher.Path -ForegroundColor white
    $watcher.Filter = "*.*" 
Write-Host "Filtering by: " $watcher.Filter -ForegroundColor white
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
Write-Host "Including Subdirectories" -ForegroundColor white
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED

$action = 
    {
    $fileName = Split-Path $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath -leaf
Write-Host $fileName
        If ($fileName -like '*.pdf')
            {
                 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
###PDF
                Write-Host "1. New File has been Created in: " $path -ForegroundColor green
                                $path2 = $path.replace("C:\Users\Demo Site - Staging\", "")
                Write-Host "`n 2. Removing the begining of directory from Path: " $path2 -ForegroundColor green
                                $path2 = $path2.replace("\","/")
                Write-Host "`n 3. Replacing \ with / in order to get file to copy to SP: " $path2 -ForegroundColor green
                                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                Write-Host "`n 4. File was changed - Type: " $changeType -ForegroundColor green
                                $logline = "$(Get-Date -Format F) , `r`n File was $changeType in: `r`n $path"
                Write-Host "`n 5. Creating a line for the logs: " $logline -ForegroundColor green
                $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                            Add-content -Path $logFile -value $logline  
                Write-Host "`n New line added to the log ${logline}"  -ForegroundColor green
                                #moves the file captured by the watcher
                Write-Host "`n 6. Waiting 2 seconds before moving to ensure file uploads succesfuly" -ForegroundColor green
                                Start-Sleep -s 2
                                Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl "/sites/test1/Staging/$path2" `
                                        -TargetUrl "/sites/test1/Archive/$path2" -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists `
                                        -Force -Confirm:$True `
                                        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError
                                        #added to make sure that the larger files finish uploading
                                    If ($ProcessError)
                                        {
                                            Write-Warning -Message "File not copied!"
                                            Write-Warning -Message "Waiting 5 seconds and trying again"
                                            Start-Sleep -s 5
                $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                                            Add-content -Path $logFile -value "`r`n $(Get-Date -Format F), `r`n Error while Copying file - Let's try this again!"
                                            Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl "/sites/test1/Staging/$path2" `
                                        -TargetUrl "/sites/test1/Archive/$path2" -Force -Confirm:$False `
                                        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError
                                            If ($ProcessError)
                                                {
                                                    Write-Warning -Message "File not copied!"
                                                    Write-Warning -Message $error[0].Exception.Message
                                                    $errorLog = "`r`n $(Get-Date -Format F), `r`n $error[0].Exception.Message"
                                                    Write-Host  "12. Writing to Log" -ForegroundColor red
                $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                                                    Add-content -Path $logFile -value $errorLog
                                                        $to_mail = ""
                                                        $fr_mail = ""
                                                        $subject = "An error has occured when moving in SharePoint Test Site"
                                                        $serverDetails = ""
                                                        $port = 
                                                    Send-MailMessage -To $to_mail -From $fr_mail -Subject $subject -Body $errorLog `
                                                                        -Priority High -SmtpServer $serverDetails -Port $port
                                                }
                                            else
                                                {
                        Write-Host  "`n 7. After 1 error, Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library" -ForegroundColor green
                                                    $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                                                    Add-content -Path $logFile -value "`r`n $(Get-Date -Format F), `r`n After 1 error, Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library"
                                                }
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                Write-Host  "`n 7. Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library with no errors" -ForegroundColor green
                                            $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                                            Add-content -Path $logFile -value "`r`n $(Get-Date -Format F), `r`n Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library with no errors"
                                        }
            }



        elseif ($fileName -like '*.rtf')
            {
###RTF

                $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                Write-Host "1. New File has been Created in: " $path -ForegroundColor green
                                $path2 = $path.replace("C:\Users\Demo Site - Staging\", "")
                Write-Host "`n 2. Removing the begining of directory from Path: " $path2 -ForegroundColor green
                                $path2 = $path2.replace("\","/")
                Write-Host "`n 3. Replacing \ with / in order to get file to copy to SP: " $path2 -ForegroundColor green
                                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                Write-Host "`n 4. File was changed - Type: " $changeType -ForegroundColor green
                                $logline = "$(Get-Date -Format F) , `r`n File was $changeType in: `r`n $path"
                Write-Host "`n 5. Creating a line for the logs: " $logline -ForegroundColor green
                $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                            Add-content -Path $logFile -value $logline  
                Write-Host "`n New line added to the log ${logline}"  -ForegroundColor green
                                #moves the file captured by the watcher
                Write-Host "`n 6. Waiting 2 seconds before moving to ensure file uploads succesfuly" -ForegroundColor green
                                Start-Sleep -s 2
                                Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl "/sites/test1/Staging/$path2" `
                                        -TargetUrl "/sites/test1/Archive/$path2" -OverwriteIfAlreadyExists `
                                        -Force -Confirm:$True `
                                        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError
                                        #added to make sure that the larger files finish uploading
                                    If ($ProcessError)
                                        {
                                            Write-Warning -Message "File not copied!"
                                            Write-Warning -Message "Waiting 5 seconds and trying again"
                                            Start-Sleep -s 5
                $logFile = "D:\ManagementGateway\SharePointLogs\USA\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                                            Add-content -Path $logFile -value "`r`n $(Get-Date -Format F), `r`n Error while Copying file - Let's try this again!"
                                            Move-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl "/sites/test1/Staging/$path2" `
                                        -TargetUrl "/sites/test1/Archive/$path2" -Force -Confirm:$False `
                                        -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable ProcessError
                                            If ($ProcessError)
                                                {
                                                    Write-Warning -Message "File not copied!"
                                                    Write-Warning -Message $error[0].Exception.Message
                                                    $errorLog = "`r`n $(Get-Date -Format F), `r`n $error[0].Exception.Message"
                                                    Write-Host  "12. Writing to Log" -ForegroundColor red
                $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                                                    Add-content -Path $logFile -value $errorLog
                                                        $to_mail = ""
                                                        $fr_mail = ""
                                                        $subject = "An error has occured when moving in SharePoint"
                                                        $serverDetails = ""
                                                        $port = 
                                                    Send-MailMessage -To $to_mail -From $fr_mail -Subject $subject -Body $errorLog `
                                                                        -Priority High -SmtpServer $serverDetails -Port $port
                                                }
                                            else
                                                {
                        Write-Host  "`n 7. After 1 error, Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library" -ForegroundColor green
                                                    $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                                                    Add-content -Path $logFile -value "`r`n $(Get-Date -Format F), `r`n After 1 error, Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library"
                                                }
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                Write-Host  "`n 7. Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library with no errors" -ForegroundColor green
                                            $logFile = "D:\SharePointMoveLog.txt"
                                            Add-content -Path $logFile -value "`r`n $(Get-Date -Format F), `r`n Succesfully moved newly created file to different sharepoint library with no errors"
                                        }
            }
    }
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
#    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

At the moment there is a small bug that sometimes occurs, 
I only see it failing on RTFs 
It comes up with an error:

`Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl Cannot open "Doc12345.rtf": no such file or folder.`

I am unclear of why this error occurs as when I drop in the file manually then it works.

I had a similar error before but it was caused by a different folder structure in SharePoint libraries, making sure that they were exactly same solved this issue.

Comment: The content for handling pdf and rtf seems pretty similar if not the same. If that's the case consider just using a condition up front to filter everything that's not rtf or pdf. `if($fileName -notlike '*.pdf*' -and $fileName -notlike '*.rtf'){return;}`

Comment: @Seth Thanks, I used `if($fileName -like '*.pdf*' -or $fileName -like '*.rtf'){action block}`
Now I have to see if that solves the docs that fail to process problem

Comment: Issue still persists `Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl`
I think it happens when multiple files are dropped in at once, but don't know how to solve it

Comment: Did you actually try to have a look what `$path2` contains? Did you verify that it exists in SharePoint already at the given location?

Comment: `$path2` contains the path but without the windows directory and with backslashes replaced to forward slashes, 
it works as intended 70% of the time and when I resend the files manually but when I leave it to work on it's own then it can fail, I don't know why but it seems to fail with RTFs only, I didn't get fails with PDFs yet.
It's strange that when I resend the files that failed manually then it works  without fail every single time. 
I will test to see if I drag and drop 5 files into folder will it still work or start failing

Comment: Ok, so I figured out what the issue is and it was not with the script. 
I'm still going to give it time just in case it's luck but I had 2 tasks scheduled one was the script above and second was oneDrive, oneDrive was set up to restart itself every 30 minutes so I changed it to never expire, since I've done this it has been 8 hours and no errors so far.