# Make files hidden automatically when downloaded to a specific folder (windows 10)

Tags: windows, hidden-file

I have a folder on my computer where I save all the images and files that I want to keep hidden.
The thing is, when I add new files to the folder (either by downloading straight to it or by moving files to that folder) they stay unhidden and I have to change that manually. Is there a way to set a folder in such a way that when files are added to it they will automatically turn hidden?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: To confirm, you mean "hidden" in the sense of Windows settings, correct?

Comment: You could register a `FileSystemWatcher` for EventName _Created_ and attribute caught file `hidden` in Action… Read [this thread](https://superuser.com/q/1453486/376602).

Comment: @Anaksunaman Yes, I meant in the windows setting sense (when you look at the properties and check hidden)

Comment: @JosefZ I'll take a look! Seems a little complicated, but maybe it's only because I never done such a thing